# Log4j max logs file after month Rollout

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a java application with the logging format configured as:

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="default"
    fileName="${default.directory}/MY-APP.log"                                      
    filePattern="${default.directory}/MY-APP.%d{yyyyMM}.%i.log">
```

which will generate several logs such as:

- MY-APP.log
- MY-APP.202305.1.log
- MY-APP.202305.2.log
- MY-APP.202305.3.log
- MY-APP.202305.4.log

I  then added the rollover strategy to have max files as 5:

`<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5">`

However, once the month 05 ends and 06 starts, new files will be generated use new month format:

- MY-APP.202306.1.log
- MY-APP.202306.2.log

But files from previous month is not deleted, as it does not meets the pattern anymore.

How can I configure log4j to have the 'max' attribute to also configure the previous month files in the 'max' ones?

Comment: Don't put the year, month and date in the pattern so it overrides the oldest one when it rolls

Comment: That would work, but I have simplified the scenario, the actual one we have even the date on the pattern. It makes easier to identify which log I should check if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found out we can actually do this by using the delete tag with the IfAccumulatedFileCount as follows:

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="min">
   <Delete basePath="${default.directory}/" maxDepth="1">
       <IfFileName glob="MY-APP.*.log">
           <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="5" />
       </IfFileName>
   </Delete>
</DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```